# Nuget english output on german system

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I´m using [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CreateNewNuGetPackageFromProjectAfterEachBuild/) to create and push nuget packages to my private feed.
The problem is, that my nuget output messages are in german and the scripts in this package can only check english messages to determine if a build/push was successful or not.
Is there a way to force nuget to use the english localization?

Comment: I know this is hacky, but the script is just a .ps1. So you could use something like this technique: http://proproit.com/wmi/getting-os-language/ then add another set of variables for locale and then use these based on the locale. You can event make it a pull request to the original package to improve it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing the strings in the script to the german outputs of nuget.